# show datatable alert

Tags: jquery, datatable, alert

i have a problem, after i'm click button show this alert:

```
DataTables warning: Unable to re-initialise DataTable. Please use the API to make any configuration changes required.
```

what the meaning of this alert??what must i do?i want after click button data grid can show data...

Comment: Your worst problem is that you haven't given any detail. Where did you see this error? What kind of program? What technology were you using, etc?

Comment: sorry..i'm using jquery for my web page...

Comment: why?... what did the button do on click?

Comment: after click button datagrid show at datatable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#show").click(function(event){
                        if (typeof oTable=='undefined'){
                                oTable = $("#datalist").dataTable({
                                .
                                .
                                .
                                });
                        }else{
                                oTable.fnDraw();
                                }
                     });
```